# Filter multidimensional numpy array using the percentile of each slice

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape x,y,z which represents z matrixes of x by y. I can slice each of the matrixes and then use clip with percentiles to filter out outliers:

```
mx = array[:, :, 0]  # taking the first matrix
filtered_mx = np.clip(mx, np.percentile(mx, 1), np.percentile(mx, 99))
```

Is there some efficient way to do the same without doing it on a slice at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arrays to `np.clip`, so it is possible to have different limits across the `z` dimension of `mx`:

```py
import numpy as np

# Create random mx
x, y, z = 10, 11, 12
mx = np.random.random((x, y, z))

# Calculate the percentiles across the x and y dimension
perc01 = np.percentile(mx, 1, axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)
perc99 = np.percentile(mx, 99, axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)

# Clip array with different limits across the z dimension
filtered_mx = np.clip(mx, a_min=perc01, a_max=perc99)
```